# Add a button to the main_activity view with Java code

Tags: android

I want to add a `Button` to the `main_activity` view using java code , so how can i do it ?
I have already tried this code and unfortunately it didn't work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout l1 = ((RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.view1));
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText(R.string.hello_world);
        l1.addView(btn);
        setContentView(l1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't call `findViewById` before setting the contentView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ahmad has said, "You can't call `findViewById` before setting the contentView". This is because your `Views` exist within your `layout` so you need an inflated `layout` to find the `id` in. Call `setContentView()` first with the `layout` which contains `view`. Then you can find the `view` and add your `Button` to it.

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        RelativeLayout l1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view1);
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText(R.string.hello_world);
        l1.addView(btn);
   }
```